# How do I create an Observable from an Action<T>?

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I'm attempting to create an Observable from an Action but the `FromEventPattern` and `FromEvent` syntax is hard for me to wrap my mind around.

**Here's my attempt:**

```
Observable
    .FromEventPattern<Action<IStreamTrade>, IStreamTrade>(
        x => _polygonSocket.TradeReceived += x,
        x => _polygonSocket.TradeReceived -= x)
    .Select(x => x?.EventArgs)
    .IsNotNull()
    .Subscribe( /** do stuff **/)
    .DisposeWith(Bindings);
```

I feel like `FromEventPattern` may not be the right choice here, but I can't get anything else to compile.

**What happens:**

I receive a `Parameter count mismatch.` exception, which looks like this:

```
Parameter count mismatch.
Thread started:  #26
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure, System.Boolean allowClosed) [0x000ee] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Delegate.cs:230 
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Delegate.cs:296 
  at System.Reactive.ReflectionUtils.CreateDelegate[TDelegate] (System.Object o, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) [0x00000] in <370f6a6bb34048878534065376a195cb>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.FromEventPattern+Impl`2[TDelegate,TEventArgs].GetHandler (System.Action`1[T] onNext) [0x0003d] in <370f6a6bb34048878534065376a195cb>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.EventProducer`2+Session[TDelegate,TArgs].Initialize () [0x00023] in <370f6a6bb34048878534065376a195cb>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.EventProducer`2+Session[TDelegate,TArgs].Connect (System.IObserver`1[T] observer) [0x00033] in <370f6a6bb34048878534065376a195cb>:0
```

**What I'm looking for:**

I'd like to learn how to create an Observable from an `Action<IStreamTrade>`. I'm open to a solution using `Observable.Create` but would prefer solutions using `FromEvent` or `FromEventPattern` if its at all possible.

**Some additional information:**

Here's how the action is defined:

`public event Action<IStreamTrade> TradeReceived;`

[GitHub Source](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-csharp/blob/develop/Alpaca.Markets/PolygonSockClient.cs#L41)

And here is how they are using it in their example code:

```
sockClient.OnTradeUpdate += HandleTradeUpdate;

// later ...

private void HandleTradeUpdate(ITradeUpdate trade)
{
// removed irrelevant code
}
```

[GitHub Source](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-csharp/blob/develop/UsageExamples/MeanReversionBrokerage.cs#L47)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Observable.FromEvent`, which converts a generic Action-based .NET event to an observable sequence:

```
Observable.FromEvent<IStreamTrade>(
    x => _polygonSocket.TradeReceived += x,
    x => _polygonSocket.TradeReceived -= x)
.Subscribe( /** do stuff **/)
.DisposeWith(Bindings);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer, and used Vitali's approach. Here's an alternative approach using `Observable.Create`.

```
Observable
    .Create<IStreamTrade>(
    x =>
    {
        Action<IStreamTrade> aist = st => x.OnNext(st);
        _polygonSocket.TradeReceived += aist;
        return Disposable.Create(() => _polygonSocket.TradeReceived -= aist);
    })
    .Subscribe()
    .DisposeWith(Bindings);
```